# Faster way to get class instance from Ajax

Tags: json, ajax, serialization, django-queryset, jsonresponse

I have this simple function to retrive data from database:

```
function find_object() {
    $.ajax({type: 'POST',
        url: '/find-object/',
        data: {
            position: position,
        },
        success: function (result_list) {
            if (result_list.result === 'OK') {
                console.log(result_list.data.myobject)
            } else {
                console.log('not found')
            };

        }
    });
};
```

and here the `view`:

```
def find_object(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        position = request.POST.get('position', None);
        try:
            my_object=My_Class.objects.get(coordinate=position)
        except:
            return JsonResponse({'result': 'None'})
        my_other_object=My_Other_Class.objects.filter(my_ForeignKey_field=my_object)
        if my_related_object:
            my_field=my_other_object.my_field
            #do things
        return JsonResponse({'result': 'OK', 'data': { 'myobject': my_object }})
```

It gives error because `my_object` `is not JSON serializable`, but it isn't a queryset because it comes from `.get()` so I can't serialize like this:

```
my_object_json=serializers.serialize('json', my_object)
```

In the first request I'm using `.get()` because it's faster than `.filter()` (when the exception are rare, and they are). For each `position` there is only one `my_object` or (rarely) none. In the second request I'm using `.filter()` because the exceptions aren't rare.

So the questions:

1) is it faster to use `.filter()` instead `.get()` and then serialize `my_object` like above or there is some other way? Maybe a no-JsonResponse? I need the object with all the fields

2) `my_other_object` is an instance of a class where `my_object` is ForeignKey. What I want? If `my_object` exist I want look if exist a corrispondent `my_other_object` and find the value of one of his fields. For each `my_object` there is only one `my_other_object` or none. My solution works but maybe there is a faster way to do so.

Also: should I use a else condition on `if request.is_ajax()`? Why shouldn't be ajax?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

0) Django model instances aren't serializable. You can't serialize a queryset either, but it doesn't mean you could serialize an instance. A simple way to make it serializable is to get its values like this

```
my_object_serialized = list(my_object.values('the', 'fields', 'that', 'you', 'need'))
```

1) This requires a bit longer answer. There is a performance difference between just `get()` and `filter()` since `get()` can return the first instance it sees in the database, but `filter()` has to traverse the whole table. But the second where you change `filter()` to `filter()[0]` it should be equal to `get()` performance-wise. AND this is all pretty much irrelevant. Why?

`filter()` and `get()` exist separately because they are meant to be used differently from one another. If you KNOW that you only have one such object in the database or you want to verify that you only have a single object, then you use `get()`, because it raises an exception when there are 0 or more instances of the queried thing. You can even do `MyModel.objects.filter(myfield=myvalue).get()` for the very same reason -  `get()` verifies that there's only one object.
If you just want to get the first one and you don't care how many there are, then the preferred way is to use `filter().first()` pattern that will either return the first object or `None` in case there are none. And just as with getting the first item with `[0]` notation, calling `first()` on a `filter()` has exactly the same performance as calling `get()`, the difference is rather what happens on Python side.

2) Your solution is pretty much fine. For this use case, it's okay.

Bonus question: If the view is only meant to be used via ajax, I would add `return HttpResponseBadRequest()` at the end either in an `else` or just on base function level.